# Overlapping lines in AIX 5.3

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

When I type commands and hit enter my cursor line for some reason appears on the the second line from the end of the output:

```
tomcat [server] /home/tomcat: ls -l
total 24
-rwxr-x---    1 tomcat  dev         7082 Jun 23 15:44 extract.sh
drwxr-x---    2 tomcat  dev          256 Jun 22 13:25 quotes
drwxr-x---    3 tomcat  dev          256 Jun 23 15:45 temp
tomcat [server] /home/tomcat:          8 Jun 23 12:54 test_file.txt //this is the line where  blinking cursor appears
drwxr-x---    2 tomcat  dev          256 Jun 23 15:45 v
```

How can I fix it?

UPD Ok, I found out what the problem was:

```
drwxr-x---    2 tomcat  dev          256 Jun 23 15:45 v^[[A^[[Axv
```

Apparently I somehow created a directory with a bunch of special characters in it name.Apparently I somehow created a directory with a bunch of special characters in its name.

Comment: which terminal window/console are you using?

Comment: Are you sure your terminal type is set correctly?  Are you sure that whatever terminal program you're using implements that terminal type correctly?  Have you tried changing these settings?  (VT100 is a good choice.)

Comment: Echo what's already been asked - what are you using to connect to the AIX server?  PuTTY? Cygwin? Attached console? Windows telnet? etc.  Tell us more about how you're connecting and we can help.

Comment: I used F-Secure